# Cannot establish remote mysql connection

Tags: mysql

I recently moved a few websites of mine from one hosting to another, but I decided to keep databases on the old hosting.

I did all the steps:

1. whitelisted new server's IP
2. changed all dbcon config ''localhost'' to old server IP
3. even changed outdated ''mysql_connect'' with mysqli
   Still I cannot establish db connection at all!
   How do I troubleshoot this? I have bno idea where else to look!

There might be some issues with PHP in the new hosting!

In PHP settings, the dropdown menu of ''Select PHP version" has only WARNING:Alternatives  and ERROR:User options. Shouldn't there be PHP versions???

Comment: You need to post some code and the error messages you are getting. Also, "PHP settings" is not a commonly understood term -- where are you seeing these settings?

Comment: The full term for these settings used on my DirectAdmin CP is "Select PHP version". Im not getting error messages at all, my wordpress site is just saying ''cannot establish db connection'', while other sites r just not working

Comment: Again, you are going to have to provide more information. You need to log a call to mysqli_error() or something. The generic "cannot establish db connection" could mean lots of things. As a starting point, can you connect to it from another application, like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench? It could be that your MySQL user is limited to localhost.

Comment: I dont know how to access these logs :(. also i cannot log into my phpmyadmin, tried every combination. support is not online yet

Answer (score 2):

You may have to look at the MySQL user connections from within MySQL.

Here is what you do:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;
```

This will reveal where each MySQL user can connection from.

If a user has `host='%'`, then that user can connect from anywhere.

If a user has `host='10.20.30.%'`, then that user can connect from `'10.20.30.%'` netblock only.

Let's take the latter case: a specific netblock.

Suppose your new servers are on netblock `20.30.40.%`. You may have to go to each user and change the netblock in `mysql.user`.

**EXAMPLE**: For the user `myuser.'10.20.30.%'`, and you want to change myuser to access MySQL from netblock `20.30.40.%`, you would login to the DB server, connect to mysql as `root@localhost`, and execute this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='20.30.40.%' WHERE host='10.20.30.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will update every user's host column with the new netblock.

You could always use the [GRANT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) instead of hacking it like I just suggested.

If you cannot change `mysql.user` in either way, you may have to ask the DB Host provider to do that for you.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This is spot-on.  I would upvote, but have use all my votes today.